# Matlab undefined variable

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following code:

```
[w1, d1]=fit1; 
    for i = 1:10, 
      p = w1*d1+i;
      C(i,:) = p;
    end

[w2, d2]=fit2; 
    for i = 1:10, 
      q = w2*d2+i;
      D(i,:) = q;
    end
```

Where function `fit1`:

```
function[w1, d1] = fit1
w1 = rand(1);
d1 = rand(1);
```

and function `fit2`:

```
function[w2, d2] = fit2
w2 = w1+0.2;
d2 = d1-0.1;
```

I get the error: `Undefined function or variable 'w1'.`

But the parameter `w1` is defined before `fit2` is called so why doesn't this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your function `fit2` doesn't know variables `w1` and `d1`. Every function has it's own variable space, which consists of input arguments and, of course, variables defined inside this function. Function `fit2` doesn't have any inputs, therefore it doesn't know any variable. In order your code to work, you should modify `fit2` to have 2 inputs (which you are using inside this function):

```
function[w2, d2] = fit2(w1,d1)
w2 = w1+0.2;
d2 = d1-0.1;
```

And call it with it's input arguments:

```
[w2, d2]=fit2(w1,d1);
```